# Arrays in custom fields or is there a better way?

Tags: custom-field

I have a poll functionality that uses custom post type & taxonomy to define actual polls.

CPT: `poll_entity`

Taxonomy: `poll_year`

Now I need to store votes on user to highlight on voting page.
I'm saving as serialized array to `voted_for` meta key.

Currently it looks like:

```
[
   2020 => [1, 2, 5] // (id of chosen poll custom post / voting entity),
   2021 =>  [2, 4, 5]
]
```

While it's working fine, I'm wondering if it's a bad practice and if there is a better way to store hierarchies like that?

Comment: Nothing really wrong with arrays, they can be more efficient in term of getting the data, but perhaps more complex in terms of updating it - as you always have to handle all data - increasing the chance for deletion or mistakes.

Comment: @QStudio yes, true, but I just not sure about alternative, keeping data in 2 meta fiedls (e.g. one for years and one for actual items) seems to be more complex, and setting another db table seems to be overkill for this too.

Comment: Perhaps the question is about scale - if the scale - amount of data - is low, then try with the array and see if you run into issues or having too complex data - this is a theoretical question, so try to map out the data and imagine how it might grow and what problems you might have - then try it!